# Postgres similarity function not appropriately using trigram index

Tags: postgresql, similarity, postgresql-10, trigram

I have a simple `person` table with a `last_name` column that I've added a GIST index with

```
CREATE INDEX last_name_idx ON person USING gist (last_name gist_trgm_ops);
```

According to the docs at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/pgtrgm.html, the `<->` operator should utilize this index. However, when I actually try to use this difference operator using this query:

```
explain verbose select * from person where last_name <-> 'foobar' > 0.5;
```

I get this back:

```
Seq Scan on public.person  (cost=0.00..290.82 rows=4485 width=233)
  Output: person_id, first_name, last_name
  Filter: ((person.last_name <-> 'foobar'::text) < '0.5'::double precision)
```

And it doesn't look like the index is being used. However, if I use the `%` operator with this command:

```
explain verbose select * from person where last_name % 'foobar';
```

It seems to use the index:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.person  (cost=4.25..41.51 rows=13 width=233)
  Output: person_id, first_name, last_name
  Recheck Cond: (person.last_name % 'foobar'::text)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on last_name_idx  (cost=0.00..4.25 rows=13 width=0)
        Index Cond: (person.last_name % 'foobar'::text)
```

I also noticed that if I move the operator to the select portion of the query, the index gets ignored again:

```
explain verbose select last_name % 'foobar' from person;

Seq Scan on public.person  (cost=0.00..257.19 rows=13455 width=1)
  Output: (last_name % 'foobar'::text)
```

Am I missing something obvious about how the similarity function uses the trigram index?

I am using Postgres 10.5 on OSX.

EDIT 1

As per Laurenz's suggestion, I tried setting `enable_seqscan = off` but unfortunately, the query with the `<->` operator still seems to ignore the index.

```
show enable_seqscan;
 enable_seqscan
----------------
 off

explain verbose select * from person where last_name <-> 'foobar' < 0.5;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on public.person  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000290.83 rows=4485 width=233)
   Output: person_id, first_name, last_name
   Filter: ((person.last_name <-> 'foobar'::text) < '0.5'::double precision)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is normal for all kinds of indexes.

The first query is not in a form that can use the index. For that, a condition would have to be of the form

```
<indexed expression> <operator supported by the index> <quasi-constant>
```

where the last expressions remains constant for the duration of the index scan and the operator returns a boolean value. Your expression ´last_name <-> 'foobar' > 0.5` is not of that form.

The `<->` operator has to be used in an `ORDER BY` clause to be able to use the index.

The third query doesn't use the index because the query affects *all* rows of the table. An index does not speed up the evaluation of an expression, it is only useful to quickly identify a subset of the table (or to get rows in a certain sort order).

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense. However, I just tried setting `enable_seqscan = off` but the query is still doing the seq scan with the `<->` operator.

Comment: I've updated the question with the results from your suggestion.